# ¿Cómo generar una presentación de Power Point con gráficos editables usando R?

Tags: r

Un cliente me pide que entregue los gráficos de un reporte en formato Power Point y que además estos gráficos sean editables, así pueden traducir las etiquetas de gráficos y cambiar los colores a los colores y otros atributos de la marca.

Tengo el reporte con todos los gráficos en `Rmd`, pero nadie en esa organización maneja R, así que no es viable compartirles el código para que lo editen y hagan los cambios necesarios. Podría generar cada gráfico como un .svg e irlos pegando en una presentación de Power Point, pero es muy laborioso, propenso a errores y tendría que repetirlo si me piden algún cambio global al reporte.

¿Cómo puedo generar desde `R` un archivo .pptx en el cada diapo sea un gráfico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La librería `officer` permite crear archivos de Power Point y, si tenemos instalada también la librería `rvg` podemos hacer que los gráficos que iran a cada diapo de Power Point sea vectoriales y por lo tanto parcialmente editables desde Power Point, sin necesidad de usar `R`. El truco es convertir a los gráficos de `ggplot2` en objetos de la clase `dml` (DrawingML), una especificación de Microsoft para gráficos dentro de Office. La función `rvg::dml()` hace esto mismo.

> En Ubuntu 19.10 es necesario instalar externamente (usando `apt-ínstall`) los paquetes `libfontconfig1-dev` y `libcairo2-dev`, que son dependencias externas de `rvg`. En macOS no tuve ese problema.

`officer` crea una presentación vacía y después podemos ir agregándole diapos, así que una buena aproximación es poner a todos los gráficos en una lista y después usar un iterador (puede ser `map()`) para iterar sobre esa lista y automatizar la creación del archivo pptxm ubicando un gráfico en cada "hoja" de PP.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)
library(rvg)

g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  labs(title = "En verdad debería elegir un mejor valor para bindwith")

g2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(carb))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  labs(title = "Todos autos modernos")

# Hago una lista con los gráficos
gráficos <- list(g1, g2)

# Convierto los gráficos a objetos dml, de DrawingML

gráficos <- map(gráficos, ~dml(ggobj = .x))

# Creo una presentación vacía

presentación <- read_pptx()  

# Genero el archivo pptx

map(gráficos2, 
    ~presentación %>%    #Nombre de la presentación vacía
      add_slide(layout = "Title and Content",     #Agrego una diapo en blanco indicando el tipo de diapo
                master = "Office Theme") %>%      
      ph_with(value = .x,                         #Agrego el gráfico, ph_with detecta que es objeto dml y usa el método acorde
              location = ph_location_fullsize())  #Usará todo el espacio de la diapo
    )             

# Guardo el objeto presentación en un archivo
print(presentación, target = "./test_pp_officer.pptx")
```

En [este enlace](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZdVCskZEFlTs4GLNwkLxzApS2VW8uWWuoIk) se puede ver y descargar el resultado.